# Submitting an HTML form that has no name

Tags: html, forms, submit

I'm wondering how I can automatically submit an html form that has no name or no id values. I don't want to use any scripts to do so.  I want to be able to do it from within a hyperlink.  I have seen an example that appends the following onto a hyperlink:

```
&onClick="document.forms[0].submit()"
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I don't want to use any scripts to do so.*

That's impossible without help of JavaScript. I'd just use a regular submit button which is styled like a link with help of CSS.

E.g.

```
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Stackoverflow.com" class="link" />
</form>
```

with

```
input[type=submit].link {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    overflow: visible;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GDUA2/).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that either you have just one form in the HTML or change the 0 to whatever is the index of that form in the forms collection. The first form has index of 0.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Click here</a>
```

Comment: OP mentioned that he don't want to use scripts.

Comment: As you have mentioned it can't be done without javascript. I updated OP's code assuming the inline code is fine :) If javascript is strict no, your solution should be used instead. Thanks for the clarification, I should have mentioned in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear. When I said that I wanted to submit the form from a hyperlink, I didn't mean with a "Click here" hyperlink. I meant from within the pages web address. For example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/webpage?submitformhere

Comment: Do you mean? http://website.com/webpage?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3